# Microsoft Teams - Bot Health Check

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams

I want to implement a health check on my MS Teams bot but it seems that support for that was removed on https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6225.

What is the best approach now to add a health check to my bot?

Thanks

Comment: We are checking with the engineering team. We will let you know once we have any update.

Comment: Do you mean a COVID style health check or a call between a bot and a skill to determine if the skill is available?

Comment: @AndrewClear I'm not sure if I understood correctly but what I want it to somehow another application check if the BOT is healthy and running as it should.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Do you have any update? Thanks

Comment: @kylie.zoltan - Right now we don't have any update. We will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism built into the Bot Framework SDK to accomplish this. You'd need to setup an API route in the bot, and have the other service call that endpoint. Depending on your security considerations you'd probably also want to authenticate that call in some manner.

At the end of the day, the bot is just a web service using some specialized API calls to model conversations - you can add any additional APIs you like just as you would with any other web service.